# Using the DocumentComplete event C#

Tags: c#, navigation, browser

I started to use the WebBrowser control for the very first time in C#. I'm trying to do something pretty simple: to write a text in a textbox and then to click a button for login.

```
WebContest wc_class = new WebContest();
...

 wc_class.wbThread1.Navigate("http://www.mysite.com");
        while (wc_class.wbThread1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();
```

Here the ReadyState for login page worck perfectly, next continue to write a text in a textbox and then to click a button

```
wc_class.wbThread1.Document.GetElementById("field_email").SetAttribute("value", tbLogin.Text);
wc_class.wbThread1.Document.GetElementById("field_password").SetAttribute("value", tbPassword.Text);
wc_class.wbThread1.Document.GetElementById("field_remember").InvokeMember("click");
wc_class.wbThread1.Document.GetElementById("hook_FormButton_button_go").InvokeMember("click");
```

and this time, after login I need to extract the links from page.
Do somethings like this :

```
...
foreach (HtmlElement link in wc_class.wbThread1.Document.Links)
            {
                string href = link.GetAttribute("HREF");
                string fileName = "links.txt";
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(href);
                }
```

And trouble is in expecting the DocumentComplete event. The page after login is not waiting to be loaded. Why?  How to check the ReadyState of page after I click Login Button?

And how to do that for all my event in page navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to and solved it using timers. After `InvokeMember("click");` I start a timer for some seconds and on timer tick I check the `ReadyState`. If complete - stop the timer, otherwise it will fire again.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer yesTimer;
yesTimer.Interval = 2000;

public Main()
{
  webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.mysite.com");
  yesTimer.Start();
}

  private void yesTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
     {
        return;
     }

     yesTimer.Stop();
     //do here whatever you want then webBrowser1 is completed
  }
```

Comment: But what happens if the application is written for the masses?
We all have different Internet and your method may not be appropriate in some cases.

Comment: @Johnny why not? as I said, the timer will fire every let's say 2 seconds until WebBrowserReadyState == Complete

Comment: okey, can you do a complete example for this question?
i test some like this :
this.wb.wbThread1.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.wbThread1_DocumentCompleted);

it's not working sow well.